# Formatting array elements into Uppercase and lower case format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings. I need to display those elements into proper format. Like this example.

```
let array1 = ["WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL - CA"," WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL - MX"]
```

I have to display it like below:

```
let formattedArray = ["Worldwide Agricultural - CA","Worldwide Industrial - MX"]
```

There are multiple of elements so I have to save formatted strings into array. I have tried but it is not coming properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
if(array1.indexOf("WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL")>=0 || array1.indexOf(" WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL") >=0){ var locname1 = array1.split('-'); var locname2 =locname1[0].trim(); var locname3 = locaname1[1].trim(); var formattedArray = locname2.toUpperCase()+ ' - '+locname3.toUpeerCase();
```

But, it is coming in uppercase and i have to all formatted elements into array.

Comment: "*I have tried but...*" Please, insert into your question the code you used to try, so we can help debugging and fixing possible errors. Please, see [mcve] then [edit] your question, thanks.

Comment: This is a matter of string manipulations basically combined with an `Array.map()` to go over all array elements and `split` to split each elements into words. Please show us what you have tried, or at least supply us with the rules to the conversion- based on what you decide which word only starts with upper case (e.g Worldwide) and which word is fully uppercased (e.g MX)? Does all you input looks exactly like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.map()` with `.replace()` and the replacement method to convert your capital groups into lowercase groups like so:

```js
const array1 = ["WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL - CA"," WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL - MX"];

const res = array1.map(str =>
  str.replace(/(\w)(\w+)_(\w)(\w+)/g, (_, a, b, c, d) => 
    `${a}${b.toLowerCase()} ${c}${d.toLowerCase()}`
  ).trim()
);

console.log(res);
```

The expression first matchs the first character in the string and groups that in group `a`. It then groups the remaining characters in group `b` up until the underscore. Then, it groups the first character after the underscore (group `c`). Lastly, it groups the remaining characters up to the next space. Using the replacement method, we can change group `b` to lowercase, and group `d` to lowercase, giving you a capitalized string.

An alternate approach which would require less grouping is to extract the first character from the first and second group, and capitalize the rest:

```js
const array1 = ["WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL - CA"," WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL - MX"];

const res = array1.map(str =>
  str.replace(/(\w+)_(\w+)/g, (_, [a, ...b], [c, ...d]) => 
    `${a}${b.join('').toLowerCase()} ${c}${d.join('').toLowerCase()}`
   ).trim()
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what would match your current demonstrated requirement:

```js
let array1 = ["WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL - CA"," WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL - MX"]
function formatter(str) {
      let split = str.split("-")
      
      let formattedFirst = split[0].replace(/_/g, " ")
         .replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
      return `${formattedFirst} - ${split[1]}`
    }
    
let convertedArray = array1.map(formatter)
console.log(convertedArray);
```

First, it seems like you only want to format whats before the ' - ' so we split on that. Then using `replace` we turn the `_` into `' '` after which we can convert to title casing by capitalizing the first letter and lower casing the rest. Afterwards, we recombine to restore the original format of the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ["WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL - CA", " WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL - MX"];


function titleCase(str) {
  var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    if (splitStr[i].length > 2) {
      splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
    } else {
      splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].toUpperCase()
    }
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}


const formattedArray = array1.map((x) => titleCase(x));

console.log(formattedArray);
```